# Typescript property decorator issue - cannot access before initialization

Tags: typescript

I have a class like this:

```
export class Class1 {
@MyDecorator()
public class2: Class2;
}

export class Class2 {
//whatever
}
```

When this code is run, I immediately get an error about Cannot access Class2 before initialization. If I remove the decorator, the code runs.

An easy fix for this is to declare Class2 above Class1 - then the code works. But why does this not work as is?

Comment: Are both classes defined inside the same file? What happens if you move the ```Class2``` before ```Class1```?

Comment: i strongly believe that is  circular dependency related issue, one hack that i found ( im not sure if it's good or not ) is to use interface as an intermidary instead to extend directly from the object.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite nice solution here.

```
function BelongsTo(options: any) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: any) {
        console.log('BelongsTo', target, propertyKey, options);
    };
}

type Ref<T> = T;

class AttributeValue {
    @BelongsTo({ type: () => Attribute })
    attribute: Ref<Attribute>;
}

class Attribute {
    // @HasMany({ type: AttributeValue })
    // @EmbeddedProperty({ type: AttributeValue })
    // @ExcludeOnDatabase()
    attributeValues: AttributeValue[];
}
```